# RB Tree does not work for *some* unsorted arrays

Tags: python-3.x, red-black-tree

```
if(node.parent.parent.parent.right == node.parent.parent):
                            tnode = self.LR(node.parent.parent)
                            node.parent.parent.parent.right = tnode
```

This is the part of the code that results into the error. Say, the nodes inserted are 5,12,10, then it results into a runtime error. Inserting 5,10,12 would work however. (10,8,12 works though).

The error returned is :

```
File "Solution.py", line 132, in Balance
    if(node.parent.parent.parent.right == node.parent.parent):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'right'
```

Can someone assist me in fixing this? The code is already too big and I am confuzzled.

Comment: How do I tackle this case? I don't know what exactly I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you actually meant "node.parent.parent.parent" as the usual rules of RB rebalancing only require that the parent and grandparent be examined during any given stage.

If you actually do mean node.parent.parent.parent make sure it is not null before checking "right".

Comment: yes, that's exactly where I am having the issue. It is indeed that I am working with the null.right node, which doesn't make sense.